# download pdf from S3 through active admin on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a PDF uploaded in `order_items` table through paperclip gem. PDF is uploaded successfully and I can see the file uploaded by visiting the S3 url generated.

My problem is, when I am downloading file on active admin it is giving me error:

```
  ActionController::MissingFile
  Cannot read file
```

My member_action in active admin is:

```
  member_action :art_proof, method: :get do    
@order      = resource
@order_item = @order.order_items.where(id: params[:item_id]).first
@uniform    = @order_item.uniform
@stock      = @order_item.stock
if @order_item.decoration_preview.url
  send_file @order_item.decoration_preview.url,
            filename: @order_item.decoration_preview_file_name,
            type: @order_item.decoration_preview_content_type
  render :nothing => true
else
  render layout: false
end
```

end

I am trying to download file through send_file method. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `send_file` with an S3 URL. Instead I pre-sign the URL and `redirect_to` the URL. Something like:

```
aws_resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(credentials: credentials)
presigner = Aws::S3::Presigner.new(client: aws_resource.client)
redirect_to presigner.presigned_url(:get_object, bucket: bucket_name, key: file.key)
```